How to make system buttons dark on mobile website
I have a webapp and I want the system buttons on mobile browsers to be dark since it really does not look good in white (see photo)
I already tried to set the theme-color and background color in meta tags as well as
theme_color and background_color in the manifest.json but I cannot get it black for some reason.


I hope you set theme_color instead of them_color?

please read How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
